# How to get an element from argv[]

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, main-method

This is C++

At the windows cmd line user types

```
p3.exe X <data.txt
```

where "p3.exe" is the program name,

"X" will be a 1, 2, or 3,

and "data.txt" is some text file program uses for input.

Inside the main method, I'm expecting argv[1] to equal the string X typed at the cmd line.  In fact, if I do

```
wcout << argv[1]
```

the output is "X" as expected.

So now I do this,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     if (argc > 1)
     {
          if (argv[1] == "X")
          {
              //do stuff
          }
     }
     return 0;
}   // end main
```

But (argv[1] == "X") never evaluates to true

What am i missing or not understanding?

Comment: And what value is stored in `argv[1]`? Did you try using a debugger, to step through your code, to find that out?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The question says that OP did.

Comment: @interjay Oh, didn't notice that :/ Probably skimmed the question to fast :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare C-style strings (`char *`) with `==` because it only compares the pointer and not the pointed-to string.

You can either use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "X") == 0)
```

or make sure at least one side of the comparison is a C++ string:

```
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "X")
```

Comment: Both work perfectly.   So the 2nd answer works by "casting" the argv[1] pointer to a string?

Comment: Yes, it copies the C string into a temporary std::string object, which is used to perform the comparison. If you wanted to compare `argv[1]` with multiple values, you can create the string in a separate line and then compare it with each value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(strcmp(argv[1],"X")==0) ...`. Should solve the Problem.